# I can't set Line Width to 1 pixel in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, width, line, jogl, antialiasing

I'm trying to set some line loops to 1 pixel width, but I always get some antialiasing effect when the width number is an odd number

Here some example code:

```
                    gl2.glLineWidth(1.0f); 
                    gl2.glBegin(GL2.GL_LINES); 
                        gl2.glVertex2i(-10, 0); 
                        gl2.glVertex2i(-10, 10); 
                    gl2.glEnd(); 

                    gl2.glLineWidth(2.0f); 
                    gl2.glBegin(GL2.GL_LINES); 
                        gl2.glVertex2i(-10, -10); 
                        gl2.glVertex2i(-10, 0); 
                    gl2.glEnd(); 

                    gl2.glLineWidth(3.0f); 
                    gl2.glBegin(GL2.GL_LINES); 
                        gl2.glVertex2i(-10, -20); 
                        gl2.glVertex2i(-10, -10); 
                    gl2.glEnd(); 

                    gl2.glLineWidth(4.0f); 
                    gl2.glBegin(GL2.GL_LINES); 
                        gl2.glVertex2i(-10, -30); 
                        gl2.glVertex2i(-10, -20); 
                    gl2.glEnd(); 

                    gl2.glLineWidth(5.0f); 
                    gl2.glBegin(GL2.GL_LINES); 
                        gl2.glVertex2i(-10, -40); 
                        gl2.glVertex2i(-10, -30); 
                    gl2.glEnd();
```

produces this (in order from up to down):

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1401029/LineWidth.png

gl2.glIsEnabled(GL2.GL_LINE_SMOOTH) returns false and gl2.glhint doesnt seem to affect it at all

any ideas?

Comment: What is your projection matrix?

Comment: Ciao Luca :)

It's the identity one

gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();

            //  map a 2D bild width*height on OpenGL
            glu.gluOrtho2D(-width/2, (width+1)/2, -(height+1)/2, height/2);
            
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://download.java.net/media/jogl/jogl-2.x-docs/javax/media/opengl/GLCapabilities.html#setNumSamples%28int%29), JOGL defaults to MSAAx2.

`setNumSamples(1)` at init time should do the trick, but you'll loose antialiasing completely. What about calling glLineWidth with `NumSamples` times the desired value ?

Comment: Which solution ? Can you confirm (or not) that for polygons, setNumSamples() disables antialiasing ?

Answer (score 1):

Before it need to be clarified that [OpenGL specification is not pixel-exact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922526/opengl-deterministic-rendering-between-gpu-vendor). Indeed you cannot pretend to have the very same result on every OpenGL implementation.

However, on mostly controllable input values the polygon rasterization give stable results on different implementations.

From you comment, this is how you setup the modelview/projection matrix:

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity(); // map a 2D bild width*height on OpenGL
glu.gluOrtho2D(-width/2, (width+1)/2, -(height+1)/2, height/2);
gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

I don't know `width` or `height` types and values, not even the viewport... but to give you this answer, I assume that you have a viewport `width` x `height`, where `width` and `height` are the variables that you use in your code, and their values are set to `100`.

Indeed you will suggest you to setup your projection matrix in this way:

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity(); // map a 2D bild width*height on OpenGL
glu.gluOrtho2D(-width/2, +width/2, -height/2, height/2);
gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

To get most scalability I suggest you to append the following modelview matrix translation:

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glTranslate(0.376, 0.376, 0.0);
```

I don't know the particoulars of the java OpenGL bindings, but follow also what *Calvin1602* have said (disable multisampling).