# OpenGL draw difference between 2 computers

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I try to unit test my render engine by comparing two `QImage` generated with [`grabFrameBuffer()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qglwidget.html#grabFrameBuffer).

It works perfectly on my laptop (Mac OS 10.9.2 non retina) and perfectly on my co-worker laptop (which is retina). But when I try to run the tests [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/) it generate the image but with a diff ±5% from the one I generated.

I'm using `Qt 5.2.1`, don't hesitate to ask for any more info

Comment: is that diff even worth worrying about? all you need for good graphics is good enough

Comment: @ratchetfreak the issue is I can't automatically find if this little difference is the current one (kind of artifact) or coming from a bug

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenGL deterministic rendering between GPU vendor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922526/opengl-deterministic-rendering-between-gpu-vendor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The invariance requirements of the OpenGL spec ([Appendix A, "Invariance", page 600](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf)) only apply within a single implementation, not across implementations:

> The OpenGL specification is not pixel exact. It therefore **does not guarantee an exact
>   match between images produced by different GL implementations**. However,
>   the specification does specify exact matches, in some cases, for images produced
>   by the same implementation.

Comment: Any source...? Just to be sure :)

Comment: @ꜱᴀᴍᴏᴛʜ: Edited with spec reference + quote.

Comment: Well, I did my maths again and I find ±5% of diff in pixels... Is it still *normal*?

Comment: [This guy](http://arek.bdmonkeys.net/bugs/invariance/index.html) compares the output of a half-dozen GL implementations, some of which have strikingly different output.  So depending on what you're doing 5% might not be unexpected.

Comment: I think you could devise a pathological case with a 100% difference between conforming implementations. For example, if the images produced consisted of alternating rows of black and white pixels.