# Weird QImage compare result

Tags: opengl, qimage

I want to run a few unit tests on my OpenGL application. Which cause me a few issue in the past ([OpenGL draw difference between 2 computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136336/opengl-draw-difference-between-2-computers)) but now I know what I can and cannot do.

Here's a little test I wrote to check the rendering:

```cpp
QImage display(grabFrameBuffer());
QImage wanted(PATH_TO_RESSOURCES + "/file_010.bmp");

int Qimage_width = display.width();
int Qimage_height = display.height();
for(int i = 1; i < Qimage_width; i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j < Qimage_height; j++) {
        if(QColor(display.pixel(i, j)).name() != QColor(wanted.pixel(i, j)).name()) {
            qDebug() << "different pixel detected" << i << j;
        }
    }
}
QVERIFY(wanted == display);
```

The QVERIFY() fails but the message `"different pixel detected" << i << j` is never shown.
If I compare the files with Photoshop (see [photo.stackexchange](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11735/how-can-i-tell-exactly-what-changed-between-two-images)), I can't find any different pixel. I'm kind of lost.

Edit : I'm using Qt 5.2 and if I change manually one pixel on file_010.bmp the error message `"different pixel detected" << i << j` is displayed.

Comment: Are you sure comparing the name() property is pertinent?

Comment: @MartinDelille name() return the color hexadecimal code (ie : `#00ff00`) if the code differs, the pixel is not the same.

Comment: Try compare color componend instead: QColor::red(), QColor::blue() and QColor::green()

Comment: Maybe the difference comes from another parameter?

Comment: You don't mention what toolkit you use, but I figure the QImage is from here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#operator-eq-eq. It says that `operator==` would consider the images not equal if the format is different. I suspect that `grabFrameBuffer()` might give you the image in a different format than reading a BMP.

Comment: BTW, there's also what looks like a stray `+` sign in `QImage(+ PATH_TO_RESSOURCES, ...`. Not sure how this compiles. Couldn't you just compare with `wanted`, that you already read above?

Comment: @RetoKoradi I'm using Qt 5.2. You're right about the fact that I should compare with `wanted`. The + PATH... is a typo and the `operator==` works on some other bmp files compared with grabframebuffer()

Comment: @ꜱᴀᴍᴏᴛʜ Looking at the source code for `QImage::operator==` reveals that it will return false if the height, width or format of the two images are not identical.  Even if `different pixel detected` is never printed out, any one of these things could be different.

Comment: @RA. I compare image that are identical. Furthermore, it works with other bmp files

Comment: @ꜱᴀᴍᴏᴛʜ They are obviously not identical if `QVERIFY` is failing.  You need to double-check that the height, width and format are identical.  Also, you are not checking all of the pixels in your `for` loop -- the indices should start at `0`, not `1`.

Comment: @RA. Damn. You're right. Well if you want some rep ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QImage` equality operator will report that two `QImage` instances are different if the images have different formats, different sizes and/or different contents.  For the benefit of others that might have trouble understanding why two `QImage` instances are different, the following function prints out what the differences are (though it may generate a lot of output if there are a lot of differing pixels):

```
void displayDifferencesInImages(const QImage& image1, const QImage& image2)
{
    if (image1 == image2)
    {
        qDebug("Images are identical");
        return;
    }

    qDebug("Found the following differences:");
    if (image1.size() != image2.size())
    {
        qDebug("    - Image sizes are different (%dx%d vs. %dx%d)",
               image1.width(), image1.height(),
               image2.width(), image2.height());
    }
    if (image1.format() != image2.format())
    {
        qDebug("    - Image formats are different (%d vs. %d)",
               static_cast<int>(image1.format()), 
               static_cast<int>(image2.format()));
    }

    int smallestWidth = qMin(image1.width(), image2.width());
    int smallestHeight = qMin(image1.height(), image2.height());

    for (int i=0; i<smallestWidth; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<smallestHeight; ++j)
        {
            if (image1.pixel(i, j) != image2.pixel(i, j))
            {
                qDebug("    - Image pixel (%d, %d) is different (%x vs. %x)",
                       i, j, image1.pixel(i, j), image2.pixel(i, j));
            }
        }
    }
}
```